# Downloading a sequence of webpages using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am very new to Python [running 2.7.x] and I am trying to download content from a webpage with thousands of links. Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
i = 1
limit = 1441

for i in limit: 
    url = 'http://pmindia.gov.in/content_print.php?nodeid='+i+'&nodetype=2'
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    webContent = response.read()
    f = open('speech'+i+'.html', 'w')
    f.write(webContent)
    f.close
```

Fairly elementary, but I get one or both of these errors 'int object is not iterable' or 'cannot concatenate str and int'. These are the printable versions of the links on this page: http://pmindia.gov.in/all-speeches.php (1400 links). But the node id's go from 1 to 1441 which means 41 numbers are missing (which is a separate problem). Final final question: in the long run, while downloading thousands of link objects, is there a way to run them in parallel to increase processing speed?

Comment: Your final final question: you could use threading or queues, and each time you grab the content for "i" push "i" into the completed queue, then while threading etc you check to see if "i" has already been completed, if so, move to the next "i" if not scrape the url. Also, try using `beautifulsoup` for parsing the link data. It'll make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

1. You got the syntax of for wrong. When you call the for loop, you need to pass it a an object that it can iterate on. This can be a list or a generator
2. adding a number to a string won't work. You need to convert with for example repr

With those fixes your code look like

```
import urllib2
i = 1
limit = 1441

for i in xrange(1,limit+1): 
    url = 'http://pmindia.gov.in/content_print.php?nodeid='+repr(i)+'&nodetype=2'
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    webContent = response.read()
    f = open('speech'+repr(i)+'.html', 'w')
    f.write(webContent)
    f.close
```

Now, if you want to go into web scraping for real, I suggest you have a look at some packages such as [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks Jeff! That worked. I'm a bit stumped though. About the repr function. I'm used to JavaScript and if I'm not wrong, I can concatenate a string and a number in JS.
And one more thing: is there a way to deal with the missing node id's? Like I mentioned, within that range, 41 links won't return anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, limit + 1):
...
```

range(M, N) returns a list of numbers from M (inclusive) to N (exclusive).
See https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or some other web crawling framework to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. I'm been trying to work with Beautiful Soup.